# AEC works in MediaRecorder only

Tags: android, mediarecorder, audiorecord

I have an application where I want to record someone's speech during a phone call. When I use the `MediaRecorder` object with `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` as input, the echo cancelation works just fine. However, when I use an `AudioRecord`, it does not work. I tried chosing `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` as input for the `AudioRecord`, as well as normal `MIC` input and manually attached the AEC (`AcousticEchoCanceler`) to the record.

**THIS WORKS:**

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16000);
recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

```
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePcm);
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE_HZ,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                44100,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minBufferSize);
AcousticEchoCanceler canceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(audioRecord.getAudioSessionId());
NoiseSuppressor suppressor = NoiseSuppressor.create(audioRecord.getAudioSessionId());
if (suppressor != null) {
    suppressor.setEnabled(true);
}

if (canceler != null) {
    canceler.setEnabled(true);
}
audioRecord.startRecording();

while (recording) {
    int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++) {
        dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
    }
}
audioRecord.stop();
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to add AutomaticGainControl, it says:

```
W/AutomaticGainControl: not enough memory
```

Comment: Have you checked if AEC is available on your device?  I have read that it's not available everywhere.  I feel like you'll have to use both in your app, and rout the recorder the right way depending on whether or not you have AEC on the phone.

Comment: It is available

Comment: I know this is fairly old, but have you gotten a fix for this? I'm looking into this now

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is an Android issue